# Opening a file without creating a new one

Tags: ruby, file, io

I have a ruby function that accesses files in my unix filesystem.
I have 2050 files each representing an hashed value in a dedicated directory.
The function reads a file containing email addresses and performs a hashing function, finds out the file id and prints.

Usually I do those things in Java but I wanna start doing it in Ruby. My problem is, that within my function, I try to open the correct file for reading, but I see that *open* works the same as *new* when no code block is provided. From the IO class, method `::openWith no associated block`, `IO.open` is a synonym for `::new`.

What I simply need to do is, open the file, set the reader pointer to the first available line, write and flush.
For simplicity I will put every code statement in one line. The file should be opened with its current status (see the `HERE` comment).

```
 def dispatch
  while (id=IDS_FILE.gets)
    bucket="#{BUCKETS}" << (PERFORM HERE THE HASH CALCULATION) ".txt"
    #HERE
    bucket_file=File.open("#{bucket}","w")
    bucket_file.write(id)
    bucket_file.close     
    end
    log "Writing #{id.chomp!} to #{bucket_file.to_path}"
  end
end
```

Comment: *IO.open is a synonym for ::new* means `IO.open` acts exactly the same with `IO.new`. It creates a Ruby IO object with the parameters given, rather than a file. What you need is an open mode other than `w`. In your case, I guess it should be `r+`

Comment: **@ArieShaw** from what I can gather (*i need the file to be opened with its current status*) OP actually needs the *append mode* [`a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)... But I'm not sure if that's what he is really asking. **@JBoy** can you please reformat your question and use proper interpunction and whitespace?

Comment: @DMKE Thanks a million! the 'a' mode was exactly what i needed!

Comment: I've added an answer four you to accept. Nonetheless you should edit your own question and reformat it. Future visitors will thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get *"the file to be opened with its current status"* you'll need the "append mode", [as documented here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode):

> ```
> "a"  Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists,
>      otherwise creates a new file for writing.
> ```

So your code should read like so:

```
File.open(bucket, "a") do |f|
  f.write id
end
```